# Access to the path 'mscordbi.dll' is denied

Tags: win-universal-app, universal

when trying to deploy my uwp application (no difference for Simulator, local or x86, x64), I get the following error:

Error : DEP0500 : The folder "...\bin\x86\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted. 
Access to the path 'mscordbi.dll' is denied

With the tool 'ProcessExplorer' I found that VS2015 itself is locking the file. After a manual delete, I can run a single deployment, but the second fails due to the locked file again. I already tried the following Things, without any effect:
 - delete VS-Settings
 - move projects to a new solution

Why is this file locked by Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you deploying your app on device in Release? This always happens to me when trying to build in Release on multiple machines.

Comment: No, I use the debug configuration :(

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but if your close VS with your project and delete `bin` folder from your project folder - this should help.

Comment: It helps for one single deployment. After that, I would have to close VS delete the Folder and start again... That can not be a solution. The strange thing is, that I am the only person in my team with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should close VS and reopen the project.
This is a VS bug. When you deploy a project, the AppX folder should be deleted, but sometimes VS uses mscordbi.dll during this.

Answer (score -2):

Just Restart A PC you Get Solution